# How to use both id and name in multiple image upload?

Tags: php, html, laravel

```html
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="pro-image" name="image[]" multiple>
```

When Id work Successfully this time Name does not catch image path.

That means empty Array.
But when remove Id just use `name="image[]"` successfully submit value.

Comment: Please, provide your code

Comment: Are you using a form? How are you posting the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a form, you can submit the images via Ajax using the fetch API like so

```html
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="pro-image" name="image[]" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    let form = document.forms[0];
    form.onsubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: new FormData(form),
        });
    }
</script>
```

And return the paths array for the images like so

```php
Route::post('/', function () {
    $images = request()->file('image');
    $paths = [];
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $paths[] = $image->store('/public');
    }
    return $paths;
});
```

And without a form, listen to input change

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="pro-image" name="image[]" multiple onchange="submit()">

<script>
    function submit() {
        var ins = document.getElementById('pro-image').files.length;
        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            fd.append("pro-image[]", document.getElementById('pro-image').files[x]);
        }
        fetch('/', {
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
            },
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: fd,
        });
    }
</script>
```

And access from backend

```php
Route::post('/', function () {
    $images = request()->file('pro-image');
    $paths = [];
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $paths[] = $image->store('/public');
    }
    return $paths;
});
```

Now you can see paths of the stored images in public directory on the network tab of dev tools

Hope this helps